# EF - work with universal entity in library project, when not specified database entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to create library with base repository. But I solved problem that the library dont know what DbContext will be used. That will be created through the asp.net project. This is my code:

```
class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ExampleDbEntities _dbContext;

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

ExampleDbEntities is child of DbContext. I need replace it. BaseRepository dont know this db context. What I use instead? This BaseRepository will be inherited in asp.net project where is instance of DbContext. 
Thank for advice

Comment: The repository pattern should not be used with Entity Framework. Please see the post I wrong on the subject for more information: http://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext
    {

        private readonly C _entities;

        public GenericRepository(C context)
        {
            _entities = context;
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual Task SaveAsync()
        {
            return _entities.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

    }

public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Edit(T entity);
        Task SaveAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks